# Как вывести список подписчиков в твиттере пользователя, используя TweetSharp?

Tags: c#

Как вывести список подписчиков пользователя при использовании библиотеки TweetSharp?

Вот как делаю я, но вечно выбивает исключение:

> System.OutOfMemoryException

```
long? cursor = null;
var options = new ListFollowerIdsOfOptions() { ScreenName = "PutinRF" };
do
{
    if (cursor != null)
      options.Cursor = cursor;

    var followersList = ts.ListFollowerIdsOf(options);

    listBox1.DataSource = followersList;

    cursor = followersList.NextCursor; //вот тут исключение

} while (cursor != 0);
```

Comment: А зачем вы в каждой итерации переписываете `listBox1.DataSource`?

Comment: Чего конкретно вы хотите добиться?

Comment: @VladD хочу вывести получаемый список подписчиков пользователя в listbox, что же ещё) подскажите тогда, как правильно вносить данные в listBox

Comment: Вы хотите вывести их всех? Их много, вот у вас и переполнение памяти. Выводите постранично.

Comment: @VladD да, желательно вывести их всех. с этим можно что-то сделать?

Comment: Ну, если у вас на всех не хватает памяти — вряд ли. И twitter наверняка не отдаст вам их все так просто, у него есть rate limiting, ограничение на количество запросов на единицу времени.

Comment: И ещё, `followersList` — это модельный объект, его нехорошо выставлять в UI. Показывайте данные постепенно, по мере просмотра их пользователем.

Comment: С другой стороны, вы **точно** уверены, что вылетает строка `cursor = followersList.NextCursor`, а не предыдущая? Документация говорит, что в курсоре 5000 элементов, хватает ли у вашего UI памяти?

Comment: @VladD вот скриншот: http://cs627224.vk.me/v627224952/81849/_FIUxDF2F6c.jpg Я знаю о лимите, поэтому и не понимаю, почему выбивает ошибка. Поставил Sleep(1000), но думаю, не в этом дело

Comment: Хм. А где на скриншоте `OutOfMemoryException`? (И для отладки скриншоты бесполезны, давайте stack trace.)

Comment: @VladD очень странно... но теперь у меня это исключение выбивает) что делать с ним?

Comment: ну, разобраться в том, какая ссылка равна `null`, например)